# Correct git.exe path for TortoiseGit under Git for windows 2.4

Tags: windows, git, tortoisegit

I have installed the [Git for windows 2.4.1 release candidate (64bit)](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.4.2.windows.1/Git-2.4.2.1-release-candidate-64-bit.exe)

It seems that after installation the following has been added to the system path

```
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin
```

But with that setting it seems that TortoiseGit stops working. When I try to do a git operation in TortoiseGit, it cannot find my git username anymore.

[image]

I have version 1.8.14.0 of TortoiseGit, which is the [latest](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/wiki/Download).

The TortoiseGit `Git.exe Path` setting currently points to `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd`.

In the TortoiseGit documentation it states

> There is a known issue in msysGit/Git for Windows: Git for Windows
>   provides two git.exe-files (one in a folder named bin and one in a
>   folder named cmd). Make sure Git.exe Path points to the bin-folder
>   within the Git for Windows installation folder.

In Git 2.4 there is a folder `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`, but that no longer contains the git.exe binary.

The `git.exe` binary is found in both `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd` and `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin` but neither of those settings work for TortoiseGit.

Comment: The error raised isn't about not finding the executable, it's not finding your `.gitconfig` file. Did you already have a `.gitconfig` set up before upgrading to 2.4.1? If so, TortoiseGit may not be looking in the correct home directory for it.

Comment: @jeremytwfortune yeah, I guess you could be right. But I do have a `.gitconfig` and it works fine with git commandline and Git Extensions.

Comment: Check to see that the `.gitconfig` you have defined is in your `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` directory in the Windows environment variables.

Comment: @jeremytwfortune you were right. By setting %HOME% explictly, my problems went away. Strange that git.exe itself worked well without HOME set correctly.

Comment: If that worked for you, would you mind marking my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check to make sure that your `%HOME%` variable in Windows is set so that TortoiseGit can find your `.gitconfig` file.

Answer (score 10):

All of these answers are wrong.
The Git.exe Path in setting is set incorrect.

Steps to fix:

1. Right click on git respostory
2. Select TottoiseGit | Settings
3. You will get the warning dialog
4. Dismiss it
5. You will get another dialog, select ignore
6. Settings will launch
7. Select: General (at the top of the tree)
8. In the edit field for Git.exe path (half way down) enter the Git.exe path
   (in my case C:\ProgramFiles\Git\bin)

That's it!

Comment: Worked well for me with TortoiseGIT 2.6.0.0 and git.exe 2.16.2 , thanks!

Answer (score 1):

TortoiseGit 1.8.14.1 ([preview release](https://download.tortoisegit.org/tgit/previews/)) has full support for Git for Windows 2.x (no need for workarounds with adding unneeded folders to `%PATH%`). Before this version, TortoiseGit cannot find the git system config of Git for Windows 2.x.

The warning you are getting means that you haven't set up the `user.name` and `user.email` git config settings. This can be done for a project or also globally (in `%HOME%\.gitconfig`: TortoiseGit here uses the `%HOME%` environment variable - if it is not set TortoiseGit uses your Windows home directory automatically).

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same error. I installed git from [here](https://git-scm.com/downloads). And then tried to install tortoisegit, it worked.